# Is an english.stackexchange user expected to have searched at onelook.com?

Tags: discussion, comments, down-votes, etiquette, new-users

Is an `english.stackexchange` user expected to have searched at [onelook.com](http://onelook.com) before asking a question about a word?

If so, should it not mention such an expectation in the Help or Tour sections of the site?

I, for one, had never heard of this site before, although I am familiar with a variety of dictionaries available both off and online.

My prompt for asking is [this question I asked](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229377/could-impliant-be-a-proper-word-meaning-opposite-of-pliant) where I seemed to receive both downvotes and comments suggesting I didn't do enough prior research, as well as a comment suggesting that I should have guessed `unpliant` based upon the word I was asking about, `impliant`.

Comment: [1/2] It doesn't have to be OneLook.com -- or any specific dictionary, of course -- but if you're asking about the meaning of a word, it **is** expected that you check *some* reliable dictionary first.  If, after having done that, you're still confused, ask your question, referring to the dictionary you checked (a quote and a link is always nice), and describing the specific point that still confuses you. In other words, like any other SE site, you *are* expected to do some basic research first, and not simply try to offload that work onto other users.

Comment: [2/2] In the case of this question, you do explicitly state you checked a dictionary, which seems sufficient to me (though the question's reception would probably have been improved if you'd mentioned specifically which dictionary you used). As an aside, you may be interested [in this question and answer on good, freely-available English language resources](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2574/55623).

Comment: Cool. I'll update to mention which dictionaries I checked.